# matlab optimizing the use of factorial

Tags: matlab, optimization, factorial

I am optimizing my code that calculates a lot of the same factorials over and over. The calls are from a few different functions so I wanted to avoid giving the array with the pre-calculated factorials as an argument to each of the functions, although I think this would be the fastest method.

Using a global variable works better, but it still isn't as fast as I would expect it to be as the loading of the global variable now takes almost as long as the calculation of the factorial.

```
function [ facn ] = cfactorial( n )

global facs

if n > 170
    facn = Inf;
elseif n == 0
    facn = 1;
else  
    facn = facs(n);
end
```

I also tried setting it persistent, which is also not much faster.

```
function [ facn ] = cfactorial( n )

persistent facs

if isempty(facs)
    load('facs.mat')
    facs = faccs;
end

if n > 170
    facn = Inf;
elseif n == 0
    facn = 1;
else  
    facn = facs(n);
end
```

In both cases the line "persistent facs" resp. "global facs" now takes most of the time in the profiler.

Is there another way to do this? Can I define something like a variable that is available globally without loading it?

Comment: Why dont you pre-compute an array of all the values and then get them from there?

Comment: That is what I do, I'm looking for an efficient way to share the array between all the functions. For now i added an extra argument where I pass that array around, but that's what I wanted to avoid. I'm mostly interested if there is a more elegant and efficient way which i don't know yet.

Comment: What about using the built-in gamma function?

Comment: As you are not modifying the array it would actually be only passed as a reference, and would not cause efficiency problems. [Can MATLAB pass by reference?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/152-can-matlab-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Maybe you should also questionif it is really required to compute all these factorials.

Comment: @erwin what would be the advantage of the gamma function versus the factorial? is it faster principally?

Comment: @mpaskov That is what I am doing at the moment, but also what I wanted to avoid :-P I was checking if there is a "simpler" method like a global variable which is still fast

Comment: Sorry. The `gamma` suggestion was not my best. I thought it could compare ok with a hand written factorial in Matlab. Also there is a gammaln which often can help in cases where a large argument is used.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid calling functions and using `if..else` as much as possible. Vectorization is the better approach.
you can make factorial matrix as this:

```
factorials = [1 cumprod(1:170) Inf];
```

assume that you want call factorial 5 times with value of `n`s are

```
ns = [3  0  56 23 456];
```

so you can get factorials as bellow:

```
f_ns = factorials(min(ns, 171) + 1) ;
```

then you continue computations with values of `f_ns`.

If you can not precompute `f_ns` you may create an inline function `facn` inside the function that needs mutiple computation of factorial and call `facn` multiple times:

```
function myfunction
    factorials = [1 cumprod(1:170) Inf];
    facn =@(n)  factorials(min(n, 171) + 1) ;
    facn(3);
    facn(0);
    facn(456);
end
```

Comment: replacing the if..else with f_ns = factorials(min(ns, 171) + 1); seems like a good idea. I'm using [external functions](http://massey.dur.ac.uk/jdp/code.html#angmom) where there are a lot of nested function calls - so it is hard to vectorize if i want to use those. Maybe I will write them myself to optimize it